# How to convert a .csr to .crt using openssl?

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

well i have tried the below

```
openssl x509 -req -in <cert_name>.csr -signkey <key_name>.key -out output.crt
```

but seems to throw an error

```
140735226307408:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: CERTIFICATE REQUEST
```

Any solutions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The source of the problem is the form of your CSR : While working with X509, your data can be store using 2 forms : DER and PEM.

By default openssl assumes you are using PEM.

In your case, you should first convert the CSR in PEM format :
**openssl req -inform DER -in <cert_name>.csr -out <cert_name>.pem**
And then
**openssl x509 -req -in <cert_name>.pem -signkey <key_name>.key -out output.crt**

Comment: Would you please put the full command syntax. Thank you

Comment: @McLan It's already full command.

Comment: for the ones getting an error for wrong tag libressl, just remove the -inform DER option